# AmpScript file attachment to email

Tags: email, ampscript, attachment

Trying to switch out the static attachment in an email to dynamic based on a Data Extension(DE).

The Static:

```
%%[
%%=AttachFile("FTP","AIDI.pdf")=%%
]%%
```

And what I'm tried to replace it with:

```
%%[ var @Program,@ColumnProgramCode  set @ColumnProgramCode = Lookup("Program_Interest_G", "ProgramCode", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program)]%%
%%[
%%=AttachFile('FTP',%%@ColumnProgramCode%% +'.pdf')=%%
]%%
```

The DE is Program_Interest_G
the filed name is ProgramCode

Answer (score 0):

I’ve got this working great now when the @file is not empty. However when it is empty the email fails. I’ve tried an if statement but it’s not working

```
%%[ var @Program,@ColumnProgramCode , @file set @Program =v([Lead:Global_Program_of_Interest_2__c]) set @ColumnProgramCode = Lookup("Program_Interest_G", "ProgramCode", "ProgramOfInterest", @Program) SET @file = Concat(@ColumnProgramCode, '.pdf') ]%%

%%[IF NOT EMPTY(@file) THEN]%%

%%=AttachFile('FTP',@file)=%% 

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. It had nothing to do with the ampscript. The Dynamic email criteria was not set correctly